# Retrieving action's title using graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am using the following query in Graph API explorer and i only want to get the title fields of previously posted actions on timeline, but the problem is that using the code below i am getting all fields like: title, image, URL etc.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/app_namespace:read/article?fields=title
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, `fields` only works on a subset of Graph API calls, e.g. `/me`, but the Facebook Documentation does say it should work in *most* areas. It could be a bug, but I don't see any reference to it being part of the Object / Actions.

I would file a bug and see if it's 'as designed'.